# Call a looped function within a function

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to get a bit of code in jQuery to work... I want a function to fire, then loop after an initial set delay.

Code I am trying to go with is:

```
var delayTime = 1000; 

setTimeout(function(){
    function doLoop () {    
        var RandomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1 
        console.log("do loop")
        var baubleSelected = ".bauble_0"+RandomID;
        $(baubleSelected).toggleClass("bauble_fadeOut");
    }
    doLoop();
}, delayTime*9);
```

So, after initial 9000ms delay, call the function "doLoop". Work out a random integer and add that to a class name, then add the "bauble_fadeOut" class to that randomly selected element, that all works...

What is missing, is to get this "doLoop" function to happen again after a short delay - so we randomly then find another randomly selected element and toggle the "bauble_fadeOut" class on it .... repeating forever...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just looking for `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: Sounds like you want a `setInterval()` inside the `setTimeout()`

Comment: No, not with the random delay aspect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there's no mention of random delay,only picking out a 'randomly selected element'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Wow. I seem to have just completely misread this, I thought it was *both*! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can simplify your call: you don't need the inner `doLoop` function:

```
var delayTime = 1000; 

setTimeout(function(){
    var RandomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1 
    console.log("do loop")
    var baubleSelected = ".bauble_0"+RandomID;
    $(baubleSelected).toggleClass("bauble_fadeOut");
}, delayTime*9);
```

Now, it's simple to make this happen repeatedly. Either use `setInterval` or put a call to `setTimeout` at the end of the callback function:

```
var delayTime = 1000; 

setInterval(function(){
    var RandomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1 
    console.log("do loop")
    var baubleSelected = ".bauble_0"+RandomID;
    $(baubleSelected).toggleClass("bauble_fadeOut");
}, delayTime*9);

// OR

var delayTime = 1000; 

setTimeout(function doLoop(){
    var RandomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1 
    console.log("do loop")
    var baubleSelected = ".bauble_0"+RandomID;
    $(baubleSelected).toggleClass("bauble_fadeOut");

    setTimeout(doLoop, delayTime*9);
}, delayTime*9);
```